# Can't understand what a variable is when trying to make form Update Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel

I have been learning Laravel 5 from Laracasts, but I met something I can't understand, here is the video link
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/13 (min 8:30)

the part that I don't understand is

```
{!!Form::Open(['method'=>PATCH, 'action'=> ['ArticlesController@Update', $article->id]]) !!}
```

I don't undertstand what $article->id is and where it comes from, I need to know this in order to understand the equivalent variable in my own project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `$article` object is passed to the view, something like:

```
public function patchAction() {
    $article = // some query for article 
    return view('your_view, ['article' => $article]);
}
```

It is needed since your are editing an article object.

Comment: *solved after I add it to the routes, thanks anyway!
Okay, I found the right variable which is equivalent to the $article in that problem, but now I got a problem 
Action App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@update not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\member\edit.blade.php)
even though I already have update function in MemberController

Comment: That means that your either don't have the method `public function update(){}` in your MemberController, or you did not assign a resourceful route to the controller `Route::resource('members','MemberController')`, or an implicit route like `Route::patch('members/{id}/update', 'MemberController@update')` or if any of those don't seem to file the issue, then your MemberController is not in the directory Laravel expects it to be, so you should search on how to handle that issue.